# Cordova Firebase Plugin Notification - Cannot add task ':processDebugGoogleServices' as a task with that name already exists

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, phonegap-plugins, firebase-cloud-messaging

i'm trying to add Google Firebase Notifications on my Phonegap Cordova app, built with Ionic. I've already installed successfully a Google Plus plugin for login (i think this would be a useful info).

I only need this Firebase plugin to complete my job but i've been stopped by this error when i build my app for Android.

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>   Cannot add task ':processDebugGoogleServices' as a task with that name already exists.

I follow this tutorial for setup [Cordova Plugin Firebase Cloud Messaging For Android](http://lokesh-patel.blogspot.it/2016/06/cordova-plugin-firebase-cloud-messaging.html)

Here is my build.gradle file edited as the tutorial said:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  buildscript {
    repositories {
       mavenCentral()
       jcenter()
    }


  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
  }
}

--------


dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
   // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
   debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
   releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
   compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.2.0"
   compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.2.0"
   compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+"
   compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+"
   compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1"
   compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2"
   // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 6):

Had the same issue. It appears com.android.application already includes google-services. 
To fix it remove:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I had a similar problem...I cannot remove it as then push  & dynamic linking will not work...Any alternative suggestion

Comment: as i ionic add "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated" plugin i face this problem..
and i am unable to get rid off...

Answer (score 0):

use `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'` instead of `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'`

and use dependency

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
```

make sure that you add the google_service json file in your app folder

Comment: Moreover i see that when i try to build, the file build.gradle lost my changes and back to original version i shared before.

Comment: i follow the code from  https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-cloud-messaging-tutorial-android/ its perfectly work for me but in new android update we need to use the above  dependency and classpath i posted above otherwise it will show error. in my opinion no need to use Cordova app plugin. if you are using firebase you need to import google sign using firebase.

Answer (score 0):

I've find out a solution.

- remove platform android from project
- add again platform android (which reload all dependencies and plugin)
- repeat all steps on that guide ([setup Firebase notifications](https://lokesh-patel.blogspot.it/2016/06/cordova-plugin-firebase-cloud-messaging.html?showComment=1484647557380#c6243241192386257691))

Everything works well! The problem was on a conflict between Google Plus plugin and Firebase which requires both same services.

Answer (score 0):

fcmplugin.gradle and build.gradle need google-services

so, change this:

```
apply plugin : 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

to this:

```
ext.postBuilderExtras = { 
  apply plugin : com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin
}
```