# Google plugin services not found, already exists when I add

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to add firebase push notifications into my mobile application, but i'm stuck in a vicious cycle when trying to build with android studios.

Firebase tells me to add the dependency into my root `build.gradle` file, which as i'm using cordova is `platforms/android/build.gradle`, so once i've added it my buildscript dependencies look like this

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' // google-services dependency from cordova-plugin-firebase
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4' // fabric dependency from cordova-plugin-firebase
}
```

and I add this line at the bottom of the `build.gradle` file also

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Then when I try to build I get the following error in android studios

> Cannot add task ':processDebugGoogleServices' as a task with that name already exists.

When I google the error, I land on [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693915/cordova-firebase-plugin-notification-cannot-add-task-processdebuggoogleservi), which says apparently to remove the `google-services` line from the dependencies. So when I do that and try to rebuild, I get the following error

> Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.

Then when I google that error I land on [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39892622/plugin-with-id-com-google-gms-google-services-not-found) that tells me to remove the line i've added, and the cycle starts again!

I'm very new to cordova/app development and i'm not 100% sure if i'm doing something completely wrong.

Incase it helps, heres my plugin list when i run `cordova plugin list`

```
cordova-open 1.0.12 "Open"
cordova-plugin-add-swift-support 1.7.2 "AddSwiftSupport"
cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.8 "Badge"
cordova-plugin-camera 4.0.3 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.1.0 "Console"
cordova-plugin-contacts 2.3.1 "Contacts"
cordova-plugin-datepicker 0.9.3 "DatePicker"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.1 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-fcm 2.1.2 "FCMPlugin"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio 1.6.0 "FingerprintAllInOne"
cordova-plugin-firebase 2.0.5 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.2 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ios-camera-permissions 1.2.0 "iOS Permissions"
cordova-plugin-keyboard 1.2.0 "Keyboard"
cordova-plugin-listpicker 2.2.2 "ListPicker"
cordova-plugin-local-notification 0.9.0-beta.2 "LocalNotification"
cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation 2.3.6 "CDVBackgroundGeolocation"
cordova-plugin-pin-dialog 0.1.3 "PinDialog"
cordova-plugin-spinner 1.1.0 "Spinner Plugin"
cordova-plugin-spinnerdialog 1.3.2 "SpinnerDialog"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-sqlite-storage 2.6.0 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
cordova-support-google-services 1.3.1 "cordova-support-google-services"
phonegap-plugin-multidex 1.0.0 "Multidex"
phonegap-plugin-push 1.11.1 "PushPlugin"
```

I'm thinking maybe I have clashing plugins? Can someone please let me know what i'm doing wrong, its all quite confusing to me at the moment!

**If anything i've specified above like the root build.gradle location is wrong, please let me know! As i said i'm quite new to this and i'm not 100% sure if everything i've said is correct!**

Comment: did you add `google-service.json`?

Comment: @PeterHaddad Yup, application is added on firebase and `google-service.json` file is present inside the project root directory

Comment: in the docs though it doesnt say to add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Comment: I'm currently in the process of removing all firebase plugins and seeing if that fixes my issue

Comment: remove fcmplugin and try and run it with only friebase plugin

Comment: trying that now but for some weird reason it keeps re-installing the google-services plugin because it claims it exists in the `config.xml`, even though it doesnt!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191168/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-s-r).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same sort of issue, after a private discussion it was discovered that I had conflicting plugins.

From the list of plugins above, I ended up removing

`cordova-support-google-services`
`cordova-plugin-fcm`

and kept only

`cordova-plugin-firebase`