# ionic4 Android Cannot add task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' as a task with that name already exists

Tags: android, angular, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework

the question which I'm gonna ask was had been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693915/cordova-firebase-plugin-notification-cannot-add-task-processdebuggoogleservi), [here](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin/issues/307) and [here](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues/578). Unfortunately, no one worked for me.

I'm currently working on an ionic4 application and trying to run the app on Android. I need to use both FCM and firebase phone authentication from firebase services. Firstly, I have added FCM to the project, it builds and worked fine, however, after adding the firebase phone authentication plugin using below commands using from [this](https://medium.com/@gbrigens/ionic-3-phone-authentication-with-firebase-dbed967e95ef) :

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase --save
npm install angularfire2 firebase --save`

Now I'm going to provide some codes:

**project.properties:**

```
    target=android-27
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=app
cordova.system.library.1=com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.10.0
cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.system.library.3=com.android.support:support-annotations:27.+
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.+
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.+
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/raihan-FCMPlugin.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-support-google-services/raihan-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.+
```

**Package.json**

```
    {
  "name": "raihan",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.2",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.5.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/fcm": "^5.5.1",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.5.1",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^5.5.1",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.5.1",
    "@ionic-native/firebase-authentication": "^5.5.1",
    "@ionic-native/http": "^5.5.1",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.5.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.1.0",
    "@ionic/pro": "2.0.4",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
    "angularfire2": "^5.1.3",
    "cordova-android": "7.1.4",
    "cordova-browser": "5.0.4",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^2.0.9",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": "^2.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication": "^1.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^3.2.0",
    "cordova-support-android-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "^1.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^6.0.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.13.8",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.8",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~1.5.1",
    "@ionic/lab": "^1.0.24",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~12.0.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.16.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filepath": {},
      "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": {},
      "cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication": {
        "FIREBASE_AUTH_VERSION": "16.1.+"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Build.gradle**

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    //This replaces project.properties w.r.t. build settings
    project.ext {
      defaultBuildToolsVersion="27.0.1" //String
      defaultMinSdkVersion=19 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 4.4
      defaultTargetSdkVersion=27 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default
      defaultCompileSdkVersion=27 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following:

```
maven 
{
   url "https://maven.google.com"
}
```

into this:

```
google()
```

and at the bottom of the build.gradle add:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: u mean in platform/android/build.gradle?

Comment: after bringing your changes the following error shown: What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found

Answer (score 0):

in buildscript replace your code with :

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

below in allprojects:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()

        jcenter()
    }
}
```